# How do I define columns for inner DataGrid in a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dependency-properties

I'm trying to implement a new control (XGrid), which contains a DataGrid.

Most of the time I directly bind the data through a DependencyProperty and set AutoGenerateColumns to `True`.

Now, in a specific case, I need the possibility to configure the columns of the DataGrid manually.
I thought about something like:

```
<local:XGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="{Binding SourceList}">
    <local:XGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="T1" Binding="{Binding Path=.Value1}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="T2" Binding="{Binding Path=.Value2}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="T3" Binding="{Binding Path=.Value3}"/>
    </local:XGrid.Columns>        
</local:XGrid>
```

Is this, or something similar, possible?

**--- EDIT 1 ---**

XGrid is actually not derived from DataGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed my last answer as your edit changed the scenario....

In this case you can expose a columns property and set columns into it, and then in constructor whenever your local collection is changed, add columns to main data grid.

something like this should work..

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty GridColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GridColumns", typeof(ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>), typeof(XGrid));
        public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn> GridColumns
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>)GetValue(GridColumnsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GridColumnsProperty, value); }
        }


public XGrid()
{
        GridColumns = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();
        GridColumns.CollectionChanged += (x, y) =>
            {
                dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
                foreach (var column in this.GridColumns)
                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
                }
            };
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but now I get an `ArgumentException` when I open my module containing the XGrid a second time, saying this: 
`Additional information: The DataGridColumn with Header 'T1' already exists in the column collection of a DataGrid. Data Grids can not share columns and can not contain duplicate column instances.`

Comment: do you have this `dataGrid.Columns.Clear();` in place ?

Comment: Yes I have, I traced the XGrid instance by logging a UID given in the constructor, when I close my module and open it up again (Open means creating a new instance per `new Module();...` The same instance of the XGrid is used! Its not disposed or something like this, it seems to be reused?!

Comment: is that in a template like datatemplate ?, also you can debug to check what line throws error and can handle it there isn't ?

Comment: No it's not like a template, but i've found the source of the error (my bad...).
I forgot to set `Columns_Center = new ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>();` as mentioned in your code.
It works now, thanks!